# Error in building Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I wrote an application and it worked well, but after updating my SDK and repository I got an error in building gradle. My error is in below:

```
Error:For input string: "<!"
Gradle sync failed: For input string: "<!"
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1s 650ms)
```

I already tried clean and again build. I searched for '!' character in full of gradle but not found this character.

How do I solve my problem?

This is my Gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  dependencies {
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile project(':ORMDroid')
//compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile files('libs/javax.mail.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}

}

//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Log File**

```
2018-01-29 10:44:41,232 [ thread 86]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - For input string: "<!"

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2018-01-29 10:44:41,232 [ thread 86]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: For input string: "<!"

 Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1s 167ms) 
2018-01-29 10:44:41,381 [ thread 94]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-01-29 10:44:41,383 [ thread 94]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-01-29 10:44:41,384 [ thread 94]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-01-29 10:44:41,384 [ thread 94]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
 2018-01-29 10:45:39,813 [se-915-b01]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction -   Exit code 1
```

Comment: see the IDE log

Comment: The error probably refers to a file with xml content, which is not expected.

Comment: @3iL 'Gradle sync failed: For input string: "<!"' show in event log tab

Comment: @GáborBakos How do i know, which xml content have error?